# How to Print only non-num from the 2nd col of a file in linux?

Tags: sed

My data looks

```
          ID.NO|CUST   
          1989 | BZXY-P
          17BY4| 1236
          18719| 9281
          ABTY | 49889
          56QQB| 87 BWE 67
```

I want two files out of this data,

File 1- Only NON-numerical values from 2nd col & the correspoding 1st col,

ID.NO|CUST

1989 | BZXY-P

56QQB| 87 BWE 67

File 2 - Only num value from 2nd col,& the correspoding 1st col

ID.NO|CUST

18719| 9281

17BY4| 1236

ABTY | 49889

Have been trying several times, no luck. I'm not really into core linux, but ive to find a soln for it, as i'm finding it hard now. Any suggestion or help will be absolutely a boon for me at this time.

Comment: Earlier i thought " grep [Aa-Zz] filename, was the soln! later i realized that, grep will filter out the entire line ,if even the 1st col has non-num, which didn't work acc to the plan

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** solution:

Input file `file`:

```
ID.NO|CUST   
1989 | BZXY-P
17BY4| 1236
18719| 9281
ABTY | 49889
56QQB| 87 BWE 67
```

---

The command:

```
awk -F' *\\| *' 'BEGIN{ f1="File1.txt"; f2="File2.txt" }
     NR==1{ print > f1; print > f2; next}
     { print > (($2~/^[0-9]+$/)? f2:f1) }' file
```

Results:

```
> cat File1.txt 
ID.NO|CUST   
1989 | BZXY-P
56QQB| 87 BWE 67
```

---

```
> cat File2.txt 
ID.NO|CUST   
17BY4| 1236
18719| 9281
ABTY | 49889
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When i try this i find the file 1 having all the values including non-num and file2 -empty with only headers

Comment: @joh, see the input file in my answer. Otherwise, you have posted non-actual input. The solution should work as expected

Comment: Pl see the screenshot i

Comment: @joh, stop editing my post. If you want to post some link - post it via comment. Besides, you have `head -7 565.txt` - that's not the same as the whole file contents

Comment: Sorry for the pain Rom. the file has only 7 records      http://imgur.com/a/wAGaX

Comment: I only need a file that has only non-num 2nd col values with their corresponding 1st col.

Comment: tried this "awk -F'|' '$2 ~ /\y[0-9]+\y/' 565.txt" from google search, but it's giving results, but this is including non-num values like "87 BWE 67" in the output file

Comment: @joh of course that random code snippet you got from google isn't doing what you want, it's not designed to. Why not just try the solution Roman provided - it **does** do what you said you want as you can see in his answer and if it's not producing the output you expected then your input file has trailing white space (I suspect `\r`s so try running `dos2unix` or similar on your input file first) or the spaces around the `|` are not blank chars so try changing `-F' *\\| *'` to `-F'[[:space:]]*\\|[[:space:]]*'` like you were shown in the answer to your previous incarnation of this question.

Comment: @EdMorton, yes, forgot that moment. Edited